# How was the "backcountry" underrepresented, eventually leading to Bacon's Rebellion?

Tags: colonial-america

"Backcountry" generally means the rural parts (of Virginia, where this all happened) or the lesser-known parts. They were newer settlement areas, and generally had a far larger population than the older "tidewater" region. How did this mean they were underrepresented / not represented in the [House of Burgesses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Burgesses)?

Was it because the newer regions were not yet established as actual counties, and thus not able to serve in politics?

Comment: You would have to specifically define the area as Kentucky and Tennessee while both incredibly poor at their found were both hugely ambitious too because of the belief in the prosperity that the two River Systems in their respective States represented. (The Ohio and Tennessee respectively.) Economically they were held back into extreme poverty well into the 20th Century...but this changed dramatically with the advent of World War 2 and FDR's New Deal and the Manhattan Project.

Comment: X:Y problem. Re-reading the wikipedia page, I see no evidence that the problem was caused by under-representation in the House of Burgesses.  Please revise the question to clarify what you really want to know. (the wikipedia page offers a credible explanation for the rebellion).

Comment: You must be misinformed then, Mark. Underrepresentation in the backcountry was definitely one of the factors leading to political unrest and Bacon's Rebellion. It was indeed because the newer lands were given less attention by the colonial legislature.

Comment: @Bobb   it is not a homework question but a simple wonder that came upon me while studying for a test. Try to actually provide constructive answers instead of being judgmental of others.

Comment: I'm glad to be misinformed because it gives you the opportunity to inform me!  Could you expand the question to provide sources/research/citations to support your assertion that attention by the colonial legislature had something to do with the rebellion?